# UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification iOS7 not fired

Tags: uitextfield, ios7

I'm using this piece of code to get informed about changing text of a UITextField.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textUpdated) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:self.inputValueField.text];
```

Works fine with iOS6 but is not getting called with iOS7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of NSNotifications, you can use UITextField's delegate to be notified about changing text.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

From the documentation:

> Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

Comment: you just introduce another new way but have not explain why notification not works.

Comment: This doesn't give you a callback if the textField's clearButton is pressed. I ended up using notifications.

Comment: This is missleading! This method is not equivalent to `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`. In this method the textfield doesn't have the new text yet...

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is, that you are passing the wrong object. You are passing the NSString in your UITextField, but should passthe UITextField itself.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(textUpdated)
        name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
        object:self.inputValueField];
```

This should work.

Answer (score 5):

Better using `NSNotificationCenter`. Here is a code snippet from a passcode managing section of an app.

Initialize `NSNotificationCenter` in `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

then declare its method `textDidChange:`

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[notification object];
    DBG(@"%@", textField.text);
    if(textField == self.txtPasscode1 && textField.text.length == 1)
    {
        [self.txtPasscode2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if(textField == self.txtPasscode2 && textField.text.length == 1)
    {
        [self.txtPasscode3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if(textField == self.txtPasscode3 && textField.text.length == 1)
    {
        [self.txtPasscode4 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if(textField == self.txtPasscode4 && textField.text.length == 1)
    {
        [self.txtPasscode1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```